# pycurl exit code 139

Tags: python, ssl, pycurl

I have a problem with this code:

```
import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://blackseoshnick.ru/')
c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
c.perform()

Process finished with exit code 139
```

I have 
A problem with the SSL certificate on this site and not to any site running on https, but I can not understand how to solve it, because certificate validation is disabled.

Comment: So you seem to want people to navigate to the URL in question?

Comment: I showed the URL as problem occurs with it, and not to any site running on https